# Linux Ubuntu: Script works in terminal, but not .sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

**Issue Summary:** My script works as it should when typed into the terminal, however, it does not work correctly when executed in terminal from a .sh file, why is this?

**Script:**

```
echo World of Clucky - Frisnuk "\033]0;Frisnuk - World of Clucky\a"
#! /usr/bin/env bash
BINDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")"
cd "$BINDIR"
while true
do
source /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/Frisnuk/serverconfig/config.sh
#Start Server
    java -Xms2000M -Xmx2000M -jar $serverjar.jar nogui
    if [ "`date +%w%H`" = "001" ]
    then
#Delete map files for The End
    rm -R /Frisnuk_the_end
    echo "End has been successfully reloaded"
    echo "[`date +%D\ %T`] End Reloaded" >> /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/Frisnuk/EndRestart.txt
#Change Item of The Week
    weekofyear=`date +%y\-%U`
    s=$(<serverconfig/ItemofTheWeek/item$weekofyear.txt)
    set -- $s
    itemoftheweekid=$2
    itemoftheweekprice=$3
    xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/scs-shop/itemStack[@type='double']" -v $itemoftheweekid /plugins/ShowCaseStandalone/ffs-storage/ffss_cac8480951254352116d5255e795006252d404d8
    xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/scs-shop/price[@type='double']" -v $itemoftheweekprice /plugins/ShowCaseStandalone/ffs-storage/ffss_cac8480951254352116d5255e795006252d404d8
fi
echo "If you want to stop the restart and shut the server off instead, please press Ctrl+C at this time"
for i in 5 4 3 2 1
do
    echo "$i..."
    sleep 1
done
echo "Restarting Server"
clear
done
```

Instead of working and running the server, it just says this:

```
World of Clucky - Frisnuk 
/home/clucky/MinecraftServers/Frisnuk/craftminecraft.sh: 7: /home/clucky/MinecraftServers/Frisnuk/craftminecraft.sh: source: not found

Error: Unable to access jarfile .jar
If you want to stop the restart and shut the server off instead, please press Ctrl+C at this time
5...
4...
3...
2...
1...
```

I am going to take a shower shortly, but I will be returning either later tonight, or tomorrow morning. Thank you in advanced for your assistance.

Comment: The source can be found in the terminal, but not in the script. The file location is correct, as I just copy and paste this script into the terminal window and it works.

Comment: The script doesn't define the `$serverjar` variable anywhere. Maybe you have it defined in your environment?

Comment: the $serverjar is defined in the script that it is sourcing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You put an `echo` before the shebang, so your script is being interpreted by `dash`, not `bash`.

`dash` doesn't include `source`, because it's not standard.

Correct your shebang and it'll do the trick.

---

The standard way to `source` a script is executing it with `.`.

Instead of `source ./myScript.sh`, you do `. ./myScript.sh`. They're the same in `bash`.